# Unable to set variable value in callback

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

```
   var currentLatitude = 0;

   var getLocation = function() {

   var suc = function(p) {
      alert("geolocation success");
      if (p.coords.latitude != undefined) {
        currentLatitude = p.coords.latitude;
        currentLongitude = p.coords.longitude;
      }
   };

   var fail = function() {
      alert("geolocation failed"); 
      getLocation();
   };

   intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc,fail);
}

 getLocation();
 alert(currentLatitude); //this is giving me zero
```

currentLatitude is coming as 0 because they are defined as global. the value is not getting changed. But when i do console.log(p.coords.latitude) it give me value.

I've tried many thing but nothing seems to be working. I'm pretty sure my logic is wrong.

Comment: where/when are you checking the values of currentLatitude and currentLongitude?

Comment: as i mention if i do console.log(p.coords.latitude) it work fine. But when i go geoLocation() and then console.log(currentLatitude) it give me 0 which is default value of currentLatitude

Comment: but where are you doing the console.log(currentLatitude)?

Comment: $(document).ready(function()

Comment: Can you show that code, along with the code that calls getLocation() in the first place?

Comment: @RahilWazir intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(**suc**,fail);

Comment: It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/sacq1wou/1/ (I'm using the standard `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` which I assume is the same as your `intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

Comment: I really think you are reading `currentLatitude` before the callback fires

Comment: I agree - getCurrentPosition is asynchronous, hence why I'm interested in where you're trying to do the console.log call vs where you're actually calling getLocation in the first place.

Comment: @JasonSperske try setting currentLatitude as global and then reads it after function call

Comment: I'm assuming kinakuta is working on a great clear answer explaining async code but just in case I'm typing up one right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from the asynchronous execution of `getCurrentPosition()`.  When you call it you are scheduling a request to access the GPS (or any other GeoLocation feature, it could be a bunch of stuff including best guess based on your IP address) to be completed in the future at the discretion of your browser.  Once this even is fired (and it's entirely optional, it might never fire) then your `suc()` or `fail()` will be called.  If you wrote code to call this `getLocation()` that looks something like this:

```
var currentLatitude, currentLongitude;

var getLocation = function () {
    var suc = function (p) {
        alert("geolocation success:"+p.coords.latitude);
        if (p.coords.latitude != undefined) {
            currentLatitude = p.coords.latitude;
            currentLongitude = p.coords.longitude;
        }

    };
    var fail = function () {
        alert("geolocation failed");
        getLocation();
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc, fail);
}

getLocation();
console.log(currentLatitude+':'+currentLongitude);
```

You would see `undefined : undefined` in your log because you are logging after the `getCurrentPosition()` scheduled but before it has been executed.  You should really put the code that uses `currentLatitude` and `currentLongitude` inside your `suc()` callback.  Or if you want to keep things seperated, write a `useLocation()` funciton and call it inside your `suc()` callback.

Comment: That's asynchronous execution :) I think the more you use it, the more beautiful it can become, but it takes a while to get in that head space.